# Doubly linked list in C: Why do I have to explicitly reassign head and tail even when they are not changed?

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list where you can add to the head or tail via a pointer to the pointer of the head or tail node.

This way you can just update the head and tail pointer to the address of the newest head or tail node.

I have those "pointer to pointers" initiated in their own function and stored in a structure that holds both.

When I add to the tail or head, I have to explicitly save the old head and reassign it, and the opposite for the tail. Otherwise, the structure gets mutated and the head also becomes the tail, or the tail becomes the head.

I'm trying to understand what is going on. Maybe the head/tail retaining struct has to be defined statically / globally?

Source here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dcl_node {
  char *content;
  struct dcl_node *next;
  struct dcl_node *prev;
} Node;

Node *create_node (char *content) {
  Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  n->content = content;
  n->next = NULL;
  n->prev = NULL;
  return n;
}

typedef struct dc_list {
  struct dcl_node **head;
  struct dcl_node **tail;
} DCList ;

DCList *init_list (char *content_head, char *content_tail) {
  Node *head = create_node(content_head);
  Node *tail = create_node(content_tail);
  head->next = tail;
  tail->prev = head;
  DCList *list = malloc(sizeof(DCList));
  list->head = &head;
  list->tail = &tail;
  return list;
}

void insert_head (char *content, DCList *list) {
  Node *old_head = *list->head;
  Node *old_tail = *list->tail; // note the saving here
  Node *node = create_node(content);
  node->next = old_head;
  old_head->prev = node;
  *list->head = node;
  *list->tail = old_tail; // and reassigning here
}

void insert_tail (char *content, DCList *list) {
  Node *old_head = *list->head; // note the saving here
  Node *old_tail = *list->tail;
  Node *node = create_node(content);
  node->prev = old_tail;
  old_tail->next = node;
  *list->head = old_head; // and reassigning here
  *list->tail = node;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  DCList *list = init_list("c", "d");

  insert_head("b", list);

  // If I don't explicitly save and reassign the tail node, 
  // in this case both head and tail would become the "b node".
    printf("head: %s\ntail: %s\n",
      (*list->head)->content, (*list->tail)->content);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `**` pointers in `DCList`. Shouldn't they point to nodes just like the node links do with a single `*`?

Comment: ...after adjusting the code those lines can be safely commented out. The print line becomes `printf("head: %s\ntail: %s\n", list->head->content, list->tail->content);` although you should normally check for `NULL` pointers.

Comment: Normally the head and tail nodes of a doubly linked list are the same node after initialization. Your use of two separate nodes here may be the problem.

Comment: Not necessarily, @DavidCullen.  One certainly *can* implement a circular DL list, but I don't think that rises to the level of "normally".

Comment: You initialize the head and tail of your list to be pointers to *local variables* of the initialization function.  Those pointers become invalid as soon as the lifetime of the local variables ends, when initialization function returns.  You could solve that problem by making the head and tail have static storage duration (by moving them to file scope, for example), but that solves only the immediate problem.  Your initialization function would then work properly only for a single list.

Comment: I don't think you want double pointers in your data structure.  It is possible to put such pointers to good use in simplifying the code of your *functions*, but they're not the right representation of your *data*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger good spot about the local variables. OP is using `malloc` to obtain memory for nodes and when the double-star variables are simplified, that problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `list->head` and `list->tail` are pointers to local variables in the `init_list` function.

These variables are destroyed when `init_list` returns and the memory they were stored in can be reused.

By coincidence, when you save them in `insert_head` and `insert_tail` your saved `head` and `tail` variables (probably!) get the same memory addresses, so they don't get overwritten. Otherwise, the old `head` could be overwritten by `node`.

This is an approximate explanation - it's hard to tell what the compiler is actually doing. But the key point is that `head` and `tail` are destroyed when `init_list` returns and then your `list->head` and `list->tail` are pointing to free memory that can be reused.